# How to create 2 Dimensional ArrayList and set values it in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a 2 dimensional array and fill it at start :

```
public static String [][] BooksList =
    {
        {"Coders at Work",null},
        {"Code Complete",null},
        {"The Mythical Man Month",null},
        {"Don’t Make Me Think, Revisited",null},
        {"The Pragmatic Programmer",null}
    };
```

I want to add more rows anytime. But array class doesn't allow increase the size of array. So i must use ArrayList like this :

```
ArrayList<List<String>> BooksList= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

But i don't know how to fill it like arrays.

Comment: Use Arrays.asList

Comment: @texasbruce That doesn't allow for increasing the size of the list either.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ArrayList Javadoc?  Is anything about it unclear?

Comment: The second dimension of your array is always null. Can you explain your need/use case ? It seems a xy problem.

Comment: @JoeC yes i saw them but i'm confusing .. need a simple example.

Comment: Please clarify what is confusing you, and please be as specific as possible.

Comment: In this case it looks like you should just create a "Book" class and create a `List<Book>`. why are you storing data in multi-dimensional arrays? is there something im missing?

Comment: @davidxxx It is the simple library system that anytime can add book and every book also have name of person that borrowed it.

Comment: and why not use a map so ?

Comment: @JoeC Arrays.asList in Oracle JVM returns ArrayList. Why can't it be increased? Besides, I was only referring it to fill the ArrayList. For example, ArrayList arr=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));

Comment: @texasbruce It returns a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, which is not the same as a `java.util.ArrayList`.  The latter supports growing and shrinking, the former does not.

Comment: @JoeC read the second sentence of my comment and see Jonathon's answer.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood which dimension the OP wanted to grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add items to the list like this:

```
BooksList.add(Arrays.asList("Cool book", null));
```

Comment: Thank you its worked ! and how i access the 2th value of 2th List of ArrayList ?

Comment: BooksList.get(1).get(1)
Remember lists start at 0

Comment: How to add item to list of specific row ? like: BooksList.get(0).add("YES");

Comment: BooksList.get(0).add(int index, E element)

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried this : BooksList.get(0).add(0,"Yes"); also BooksList.get(0).add(1,"YES"); and BooksList.get(0).add(2,"YES");

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment :

> It is the simple library system that anytime can add book and every
>   book also have name of person that borrowed it.

You should probably use a `Map` where the key is a book and the value is a List of borrower (as a book may probably have been booked by several people).
Using a map will ease the retrieval/modification of a specific book.
With array or List, when you want to access/change a specific book, you have to iterate the List until finding it.

You could so create a `Map` with books :

```
Map<Book, List<Borrower>> borrowersByBook = new HashMap<>();
borrowersByBook.put(new Book("Coders at Work"), new ArrayList<>());
borrowersByBook.put(new Book("Code Complete"), new ArrayList<>());
...
```

And add borrowers for books :

```
 List<Borrower> borrowers = borrowersByBook.get(new Book("Coders at Work"));
 borrowers.add(new Borrower("SaMi GiMiX", LocalDate.of(2017, 8, 12));
 borrowers.add(new Borrower("davidxxx", LocalDate.of(2017, 8, 12));
```

If you use a `Book` class instead of a `String` class to represent a book, you have to override `equals()/hashcode()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

A two dimensional array can be represented with lists like this :

```
List<List<String>> BooksList = new ArrayList<>();
//adding elements
BooksList.add( Arrays.asList("ONE","TWO") );
//or like this
List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
row.add("THREE");
row.add("FOUR");
BooksList.add(row);
```